# AWS Lambda: MP3 Reverse Proxy using Got and Streaming Reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hoping this is a simple question, but I am attempting to port a lambda function from Heroku running on a expressJS server to AWS Lambda Streaming function that does the following:

1. Accepts a URL to a MP3
2. Using the Got package, it then retrieves the MP3 *and* passes over the authentication to the link which is required.
3. From there, it stores that MP3 data into the FS and creates a readable stream.
4. Finally I use the FS stream to output that file.

I was *hoping* this would be a easy port to AWS Lambda, but I am running into a error wherein the AWS Lambda is producing the following error:

```
2023-11-21T20:03:57.728 ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "writable.end is not a function",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: writable.end is not a function",
        "    at pumpToNode (node:internal/streams/pipeline:142:16)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"
    ]
}
```

When I try to hit the API I see it streaming, but it doesn't stream any data over ~200bits.

So hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Here is the code I am using on AWS with the Lambda and Streaming.

```
import stream from 'stream';
import axios from 'axios';
import fs from 'fs';
import got from 'got';
const { Readable } = stream;
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);


export const handler = awslambda.streamifyResponse(async (event, responseStream, _context) => {
  
  console.log(event)
  
  const getAuthDetails = async () => {

        var config = {
            method: 'get',
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            url: 'LINKHERE'
        };

        try {
            let authCall = await axios(config)
            return authCall.data.response.access_token
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
    

  const url = `${event.queryStringParameters.url}`
  console.log(url)
  const authToken = await getAuthDetails();
  
    const options = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
        }
    }

    const gotStream = got.stream.get(url, options);

    const outStream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/test.mp3');

    try{
        await pipeline(gotStream, outStream);
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
    finally{
        var stream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/test.mp3');
        await pipeline(responseStream, stream);
  }
  
  
  
});
```

Things I Tried:

I tried skipping Got and just streaming directly but that didn't work at all.
I tried to see if a API Gateway could do it but I wasn't sure the correct way to set it up.

Thank you all very much!